# How to Substitute Variables in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sqlplus, psql

The given Oracle query inserts data into table by substituting variables. How I achieve the same in PostgreSQL?

```
INSERT INTO control_threshold (
    threshold_id, group_name, description, sql, low_value, high_value)
VALUES(
    threshold_seq.nextval, '&2', '&1',  TRIM('&5' || '&6' || '&7' || '&8' || '&9'),
    trim('&3'), trim('&4'));
```

Comment: In reference to [your deleted question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71462/what-should-be-the-datatype-of-column-with-hstore-values/71463): That deleted my answer as well, and I don't think your question was completely unfounded. There has been confusion before. I suggest you undelete it and edit in that your version of Postgres did not seem to support the type `hstore`.

Answer (score 7):

These variables are a feature of SQL*Plus.

`psql`, the equivalent program in the PostgreSQL world, also has variables.

Use

```
\set variable 'value'
```

and

```
insert into mytable(mycolumn)
values (:variable);
```